# Why (c++) casting from long long unsigned int to long double and back produces 0

Tags: c++, casting, biginteger

I have such program:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace System;
using namespace std;

typedef long long unsigned int T_num;
typedef long double T_ld;


int main(array<System::String ^> ^args) {
    T_num a = numeric_limits<T_num>::max();
    T_ld b = numeric_limits<T_ld>::max();
    if ( b > a ) {
        cout << "decimal is bigger than integer" << endl;
    } else {
        cout << "integer is bigger than decimal" << endl;
    }
    T_num c;
    b = a;
    c = floor(b);
    if ( c == a) {
        cout << "OK" << endl;
    } else {
        cout << "dupa" << endl;
        cout << c << endl;
        cout << a << endl;
        cout << b << endl;
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Which produces such output:

```
decimal is bigger than integer
dupa
0
18446744073709551615
1.84467e+019
Press any key to continue . . .
```

If b can contain a, so why c is 0?

Hmm... it (web page) asks me to provide more details but I am not sure what more could I say...
I expect that if a fits in b then it should be able to convert it back from b to c.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`b` can't necessarily contain `a`, only an approximation of it. `long double` has a larger range than `unsigned long long` (hence a larger value of `max`) but might have fewer mantissa bits to hold the most significant bits of the value, giving less precision for large values.

The maximum `unsigned long long` value is `2^N-1` where `N` is the number of bits; probably 64.

If `long double` has fewer then `N` mantissa bits, then conversion will round this to one of the two nearest representable values, perhaps `2^N`. This is outside the range of `unsigned long long`, so converting back gives undefined behaviour. Perhaps it's being reduced using modular arithmetic to zero (as would happen if converting from an integer type), but in principle anything could happen.

Comment: Possible, but e.g. casting `floor( 1e24 )` to `unsigned long long` results in non-zero. Namely `18446744073709551615` with g++, and `9223372036854775808` with MSVC.  Those are respectively 2^64-1 and 2^63.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: I'm not sure what you mean. Modular reduction would only give zero for multiples of `2^N`, which `1e24` isn't.

Comment: I mean, the concrete result values don't appear to support the modulo reduction hypothesis. Not sure what it is though.

Comment: Your analysis sounds good, Mike. The important thing (which I missed initially) is that the maximum integer is just 1 away from the value who's modulo is zero. For example, 18446744073709551615 is 0xffffffffffffffff, which might be rounded to 0x10000000000000000.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: I see what you mean. I wasn't sure what the conversion rules were, and guessed modulo reduction; it turns out it's UB.

Comment: Uhm, I'm not sure of the UB either. I thought of that, and dismissed it, because you can ordinarily initialize or assign to an unsigned integer any integral value. But maybe the standard limits that only to integral values?

Comment: Okay, I confirmed the UB, "A prvalue of a floating point type can be converted to a prvalue of an integer type. The behavior is undefined if the truncated value cannot be represented in the destination type." in C++11 §4.9/1 in [conv.fpint].